# Friedmann equation in terms of comoving mass density

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, space-expansion

The Friedmann equation is given by

$$\Big(\frac{\dot a}{a}\Big)^2=\frac{8\pi G}{3}\rho-\frac{k}{R_0^2\ a^2}$$
where $k=\{-1,0,1\}$ and $R_0$ is the constant comoving radius of curvature of space.

I wish to express the Friedmann equation in terms of comoving mass density $\rho_0$.

I start by expressing the Friedmann equation in terms of proper length. The reduced Planck length is given by

$$l_P=\sqrt{\frac{8\pi G\hbar}{c^3}}.$$

I set $\hbar=c=1$ so that the Friedmann equation becomes

$$\Big(\frac{\dot a}{a}\Big)^2=\frac{l_P^2}{3}\rho-\frac{k}{R_0^2\ a^2}.$$

As the Planck length $l_P$ does not depend on the coordinate system, it has dimension $[\hbox{proper length}]$. Also the mass density $\rho$ has dimension $[\hbox{proper length}]^{-4}$. Thus the term $(l_P^2/3)\rho$ has dimension $[\hbox{proper length}]^{-2}$ which matches the dimensions of the other two terms in the equation.

I can convert the constant Planck length, expressed in terms of proper units, into an expression for the Planck length in comoving units by dividing by the scale factor so that $l_P \rightarrow l_P/a$. Also I can convert the mass density $\rho$ in proper units into the mass density in comoving units $\rho \rightarrow \rho_0$. The Friedmann equation then becomes

$$\Big(\frac{\dot a}{a}\Big)^2=\frac{l_P^2}{3a^2}\rho_0-\frac{k}{R_0^2\ a^2}.$$

Is this valid? Have I successfully re-expressed the Friedmann equation in terms of comoving mass density $\rho_0$?

Maybe the following is a better way to think about the conversion from proper length to comoving length?

$$l_P^2\rho \equiv \frac{1}{L^2} \equiv \frac{1}{a^2 L_0^2} \equiv \frac{l_{P0}^2 \rho_0}{a^2}=\frac{l_{P}^2 \rho_0}{a^2}$$

since $l_{P0}=l_P$ when $t=0$. $L$ is some proper length and $L_0$ is some comoving length such that $L=a\ L_0$.

Comment: I think there's a problem with the last statement, since it assumes that $l_{P0} =  l_P$, but you already said that $l_P = a l_{P0}$

Comment: What will vary is the density. $\rho$ is constant for the vacuum energy density. For radiation $\rho~=~\rho_0/a^4$ and for matter $\rho~=~\rho_0/a^3$.